# Encrypt a song in javascript

Tags: javascript, web-applications, encryption

I have done a web app for mobiles where you have a music player. It is working fine but the idea now is to be possible to listen to that music when it is offline, the song file must be only to use with the web app. For that I will need to encrypt the song to be able to listen only with the music player.

Is possible to make it with javascript? Anyone knows an example or documentation about how to proceed?

Comment: Stop trying to do things where much smarter people already failed. If your client-side player can decrypt it so can the user. And by adding DRM you just make yourself a **very damn attractive target** to anyone smart enough to break it. *Because nobody likes DRM.*

Comment: BTW, you may be surprised to learn that your music is probably already being copied from your online player. The user is playing it on his computer. The user *has* the song already. Saving it into a file is a trivial matter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Stanford Javascript Crypto Library](http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/). However, any javascript only solutions may bear the risk that the encryption key can be extracted from your app.